# Only display future dates in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, date, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm new to Objective-C and I have a `UITableView` that is populated by an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` (one for each event). The array is created by parsing an .ics calendar file which contains past and future events but I only want future events in my `UITableView`.

The dates exist as a child `NSDictionary` with 'Year', 'Month' and 'Day' keys, as pulled from the .ics file by my parser.

I'm guessing I need to create a new array, only copying in the events (`NSDictionary`)  who's date is later than the current date but I have no idea how to do it.
How would one go about such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to compare your dates and get your future date, store in a new array and reload your table with this new array.

Comment: Ok I have this working now. I used [NSCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents] to create NSDate objects instead of NSDictionaries for the dates. Then tested ([testDate compare:now] == NSOrderedDescending) to see which events to add to the new dictionary.